# how to get colliding with tail in snake game unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am using this tutorial [noobtuts](https://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-snake-game) to make snake game in unity.everything is working fine but one problem is how can i detect the head is colliding with it's tail.
the head already collide with tail that immediately behind the head.it's continuously colliding with head and printing the log.but i want when the head collide with the tail when the head move.
here is my code

```
if (coll.name.StartsWith ("TailPrefab"))
        {
                print ("tail colliding");
        }
```

Comment: Put an extra collier on head with some distance from neck. Apply above check on new collier. Or you can make it a trigger

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you'll either need to attach a separate script to the head and tail or add one script to each that knows whether it's head or tail depending on some variable. For simplicity I'll just demo the head script:
Attach a collider to the head and give it a [tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) called 'head'. Give the collider on the tail the tag 'tail'. In the head script create an collision prog:

```
void OnCollisonEnter(Collider col)
{
     if(col.tag == "tail")
     {
          //do what you want to do
     }
}
```

To clarify: you will need a separate game object for the head, tail and body.

Answer (score 1):

Your head seems to move discreetly, that is it jumps from current to next.

Then you can check whether there is already something at the target position.

```
SnakeNode[]nodes;

foreach(SnakeNode node in nodes)
{
    if(Vector3.Distance(head.position, node.position) < 0.01f){ CollisionDetected(); }
}
```

This is a pseudo code, it considers you have some kind of SnakeNode system containing the current position. Then you iterate making sure the head is not part of the collection (or you will get collision).

Comment: i solve it using simply gap between box collider 1 px.